# Factor Analysis: how to distinguish cross-loadings from correlated latent factors

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics

Factor analysis can allow the factors to be correlated in 'oblique' rotations. But this seems underdetermined. How would (explanatory) factor analysis  distinguish the two cases below (using the data only, not bringing any background knowledge about the items?

Case 1: "items A and B are both caused by factors 1 and 2"  and

Case 2: "Item A is caused by factor 1 only and B by factor 2 only, but factors 1 and 2 are positively correlated"?

Fwiw I've asked ChatGPT several times, e.g., [here](https://chat.openai.com/share/a7209b17-4e4b-40a5-a14e-32d990743afa) and it doesn't seem to come to a consistent answer, sometimes 'admitting' that it is 'hard to distinguish' these cases.

This is important for me because I come from an econometric and causal inference background, not a psychometrics background, and I am struggling to understand what factor analysis adds to principle component analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Exploratory factor analysis cannot distinguish these two. Thurstone called this a 'bloated specific' and in IRT it's referred to as a 'local dependency'.

Confirmatory factor analysis also cannot distinguish between these two - it is a case of equivalent models.

Comment: If you are right this adds to my confusion about the value of EFA/CFA in producing reliable measures. If the same data, or data from the same real world processes could yield different factor structures, how does this help me ascertain the true causal structure or develop metrics to reflect these?

Comment: Factor analysis provides a description of the data.  It doesn't uncover causal structure. There are lots of factor structures and EFA will never uncover (bifactor, correlated errors, MTMM, etc). If you don't understand your data, factor analysis can give you nonsense - give it a time series for example, and it will try to find factors.